# string python function to summarize data - code problem

Tags: python, string, function, summary

I made the string function in pythonbelow to summarize a block of text. I'm not getting any final answer when I run the function. Can someone help figure out what I did wrong? Thanks.

```
def summary(data):

    category = data.get("category", "")
    article_date = data.get("date", "")
    headline = data.get("headline", "")

    return summary(data)

    pass
```

Comment: What output are you expecting from this function?

Comment: A summary of the paragraph in a sentence.

Comment: What format should the summary be? How is it related to category, headline and article_date

Comment: The summary should be a string with formatted date. category. headline. of the paragraph

Comment: Post an example of the input data

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling the summary function. Assuming that the code provided is the entire function, if you want to get any output, you'd need to use something like this rather than calling the function again. You would also have to print the return value of the function

```
def summary(data):

    category = data.get("category", "")
    article_date = data.get("date", "")
    headline = data.get("headline", "")

    return f"Category: {category}\nArticle Date: {article_date}\nHeadline: {headline}\n"

    pass
```